# i want to match Something<alive> (match <alive> and then wanna extract "Something word from it and save it in a list)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

!!! a file avengers.txt is attached with code part read that before reading next lines !!!

I wanna match (, , ) and exclude them from (iron man, docter strange, gamora) and save (iron man, docter strange, gamora) on a list

i used `r'<(.*alive)>1` to match  and same for dusted and died. now i want to sperate `iron man` from  and save it in a list and seperate `docter strange` from  and save it in a seperate list and same for `gamora`

the code i used to match alive, dusted and died:

`````````
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

#file = open("avengers.txt", "r")

def alive():
    with open("avengers.txt") as f:
        for i in f:
            rx = re.findall("<(.*alive)>", i)
            print(rx)


def died():
    with open("avengers.txt") as f:
        for i in f:
            rx = re.findall("<(.*died)>", i)
            print(rx)

def dusted():
    with open("avengers.txt") as f:
        for i in f:
            rx = re.findall("<(.*dusted)>", i)
            print(rx)


-----avengers.txt-------
iron man<alive>
doctor strange<dusted>
gamora<died>
------------------------


````````
`````````

Comment: why are you using regex for such a simple input ?

Comment: There is no rule saying you aren't allowed to use regexes to solve simple problems. Often a regex is the simplest solution even if the problem is quite simple anyway.

Comment: @kaya3, it's not about "rules". If you would know about performance difference when spinning regex like `re.findall` for every simple situation - you would understand

Comment: What makes you think a regex will have worse performance than an alternative solution?

Comment: @kaya3, when speaking in generic about "regex" and at same time posting the answer with `re.search` instead of `re.findall` - you would need to at least confess the difference.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for a solution using `findall`, but `findall` just calls `search` in a loop. Since each line will only match once (and the whole line will match), the overhead is minimal.

Comment: @Dos_Kid, Are those patterns always occur at the end of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alive = []
died = []
dusted = []
with open("avengers.txt") as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.strip()
        if '<alive>' in i:
            alive.append(i.replace('<alive>', ''))
        if '<died>' in i:
            died.append(i.replace('<died>', ''))
        if '<dusted>' in i:
            dusted.append(i.replace('<dusted>', ''))

print('****alive****')
print(str(alive))
print('****died****')
print(str(died))
print('****dusted****')
print(str(dusted))
```

avengers.txt

```
iron man<alive>
iron man_2<alive>
doctor strange<dusted>
doctor strange_2<dusted>
gamora<died>
gamora2<died>
```

Comment: thanks again. and can you say why \n is printed in each list on o/p

Comment: yes each read line came with the newline \n, if you want to remove before to assign you can use strip method, the code is updated now

Answer (score 2):

The regex `(.+)<(.+)>` will match each line in your file. Using parentheses allows you to "capture" the part of the string which was matched, and then retrieve those parts using the `.group` method.

I recommend only opening the file once, parsing it into a data structure, and then querying that data structure - instead of opening and parsing the file for every query.

```py
import re

def parse_file(filename):
    pattern = re.compile('(.+)<(.+)>')
    results = { 'alive': [], 'dusted': [], 'died': [] }
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            m = pattern.search(line)
            if m:
                name = m.group(1)
                status = m.group(2)
                results[status].append(name)
    return results


statuses = parse_file('avengers.txt')

print(statuses['alive'])     # ['iron man']
print(statuses['dusted'])    # ['doctor strange']
print(statuses['died'])      # ['gamora']
```

Comment: Thank You so much for helping <3